# Database acces on HTML audio tag (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, model-view-controller, html5-audio

What I have is

```
<audio><source src="mysource" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

And in my controller I have something like

```
void addPlay(){
~Database access
~Song.Plays++
}
```

I tried the onplay() function of audio tag but its not working. So I wonder how can I solve this. Thanks !

Comment: use an ajax request....

Comment: ... and return `FileStreamResult` from controller action method with `audio/mpeg` content type (please include [mcve]).